Imported data in table from csv in Pgadmin4, Data not getting loaded in table
Imported data in table from csv in Pgadmin4, but it's not showing while querying the data. For Impoting I went to Databses -> public -> Tables -> Import/Export Datasets and choose my dataset from my local.
select * from imdb_top_movies;

it returns the empty table, but it should have 1000 rows
Before importing I created the tables with same column names & datatype as well.screenshot of the query

I am afraid the reason for this is that you first created an empty table, and then fill it with itself. Try using pg_restore please.

Having an empty table and filling it is fine for this step, so that is not the issue. But without an overview of your settings in the import screens, or a logreport of the import, I'm afraid there isn't much we can do/say at this moment.
